# SOAP security header to include <fueloauth> in SFCC

Tags: marketing-cloud

Was trying to include the  in the security header of the SOAP call, here is the code snap that I'm using:
[image: Soap call security header]

Getting the following error when trying to create the header:

ScriptingException:Wrapped org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog. (bc_importexport/cartridge/scripts/export/exacttarget/ExactTargetUtils.ds#366)

Can someone help me in this regard..?